# Does anyone know what the new format for direct links to App Store apps is or if that feature went away?

Tags: ios, app-store

It seems Apple has made a change to how App Store links work and I can't find the new format.

To be clear I am looking for the new format that links to a specific app in any country's App Store. If you go to the Instagram product page, select to share the app, and choose to copy the link or go to iTC and copy the 'View in App Store' link you will get `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8`.

This link will *only* work in the country in which you copied the link. This means if you are in the US folks in Europe won't be able to use the link.

In the past you could just add your app name to the end of `https://itunes.com/apps/` (for Instagram it would be `https://itunes.com/apps/instagram`). This no longer works as it opens the iTunes store rather than the App Store.

I've checked the 'What's New in App Store Connect' video from WWDC 2018 and there was no mention of any new format and using Google keeps giving me results around deep links which is not what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know if this is still possible to do, and if so, what the format is? Or perhaps I have found a bug with the transition from iTunesConnect to AppStoreConnect??

Comment: if you go to instagram website you can redirect to app store by https://itunes.apple.com/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8&vt=lo

Comment: I did cut the link to https://itunes.apple.com/app/instagram/id389801252

Comment: Looks like the answer then is to copy the link from the store or App Store Connect cut out the store designator and trim off the query portion. Thanks! I should have thought to look at other websites to see how they were doing it…